# gnuplot : value format specificiers and scaling

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot a graph using gnuplot. My input file is of the format

```
0.000000    0
0.068719    1
0.070836    1
0.071406    1
0.073363    291
0.073396    1705
0.073424    3119
0.073436    4533
0.073449    5947
0.073525    7361
0.073590    8775
0.144201    10189
0.144233    11603
0.144259    13017
0.144271    14431
0.144296    15845
0.144308    17259
0.144358    18673
0.148081    20087
0.148196    21501
0.148300    22915
0.148348    24329
```

The configuration file for gnuplot is given below.

```bash
set terminal png
set size 1.0, 1.0

set xlabel "timestamps"
#set format x "%.3g"
#set xrange [0:100]
#set xtics 1
#set autoscale x
set ylabel "highest seq number"
#set format y "%.3g"
#set ytics 1
#set yrange [0:100]
#set autoscale y
set title "seq no over time"
set key reverse Left outside
set grid

set pointsize 2.5
set style data linespoints
```

I got the graph plotted.The y-axis of my graph which is supposed to plot sequence numbers plots the following values.

> > 0,5e+07,1e+08 , 1.5e+08 ,2e+08

1. Why are the values represented in this format. I could not find any format specifiers for simple decimals. I am assuming there should be format specifier for decimals. I can't find it.
2. `set size 1.0, 1.0`
   gives me a full graph with boundaries but a graph with `set size 1.5, 1.5`  gives me a truncated graph. I would like a scaled non-truncated graph. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For setting the format to decimal, you can try:

```bash
gnuplot> set format x "%8.6f"
```

The notation `%g` you are using is the shorter for exponential notation.  Check the [documentation of set format](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node184.html).

In order to change the output canvas size, you should try something like:

```bash
set terminal png size 960,720
set size 1.0, 1.0
```

Where 960,720 is 1.5 times 640,480 (the default canvas size).